# "Duplicate 'EmbeddedResource' items were included" when using Uno Platform and Xamarin.Forms on WebAssembly

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms, uwp, uno-platform

When building I'm getting this error:

```
Duplicate 'EmbeddedResource' items were included. 
The .NET SDK includes 'EmbeddedResource' items from your project directory by default. 
You can either remove these items from your project file, or set the 'EnableDefaultEmbeddedResourceItems' property to 'false' if you want to explicitly include them in your project file. For more information, see https://aka.ms/sdkimplicititems. 
The duplicate items were: 'WasmCSS\Fonts.css'
XamNote.Wasm    C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.1.202\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.DefaultItems.targets   306
```

What should be done to fix this error ?

Comment: Can you indicate the steps you followed to get there ? Also, which version of visual studio are you using ?

Comment: Hi @JeromeLaban thanks for editing my messy First question in StackOverFlow 

Well i just added the UNO WASM to my Xamarin.Forms (4.6) project in Visual Studio 2019 16.5.5
Which uses the MasterDetail Template, a Custom font, RG.Popup.Plugin that supports UWP, a Local DataBase with sqilite-net-pcl and i really don't know why it yells at WasmCSS\Fonts.css in EveryProject.

hope this was the info that i should tell you :(

Comment: Does it happen if you follow the getting started, using a basic xamarin.forms app ?

Comment: No but it stocks on SplashScreen in both MasredDetail Template using XF 4.6(a new project with nothing more) and a blank project using XF 4.4 .

this Duplicate 'EmbeddedResource' error only happens when i add it to an existing one.

Answer (score 3):

Same thing her , just fallow the instruction her 
https://platform.uno/xamarin-forms/

first thing , it generate the Wasm project but could not add it to the sln , so i added it manually 
then when i try to build Wasm , got this error

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   NETSDK1022  Duplicate 'EmbeddedResource' items were included. The .NET SDK includes 'EmbeddedResource' items from your project directory by default. You can either remove these items from your project file, or set the 'EnableDefaultEmbeddedResourceItems' property to 'false' if you want to explicitly include them in your project file. For more information, see https://aka.ms/sdkimplicititems. The duplicate items were: 'WasmCSS\Fonts.css'    TestingWebAssXamarin.Wasm   C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.1.300\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.DefaultItems.targets   306

visual studio Version 16.6.0
xamarin froms 4.6.0.800